# Replicate Changes from oracle to Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have Oracle database 11 g in which I have many tables. I want to replicate few of these tables in SQL server so whenever a new record is inserted in oracle table I also want to update in SQL server table. I have created linked server but don't know what to do next. Kindly guide me how can I replicate changes on SQL server side.

Comment: Did you try google? Your question title reveals LOTS of solid ideas. https://www.google.com/search?q=Replicate+Changes+from+oracle+to+Sql+Server

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/heterogeneous-database-replication?view=sql-server-2014

Answer (score 0):

Use Goldengate (An Oracle tool) that can do bi-directional replication from Oracle to Sql Server. See this:
http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/data-integration/goldengate/using-gg11g-for-sql-server-1489372.pdf